# emacs + vimpulse-visual-mode + "linewise" text selection

Tags: emacs, vimpulse

Is it possible to make *visual-line-mode* (one after pressing **V** from normal mode) conduct as if *first mark* was in the beginning of the first line of selection and *second mark* - end of the last line?

For an example, currently after **V**, **j** and **M-x comment-dwim**:

```
here<cursor>is a
simple example
```

becomes

```
here;;  is a
;; simp
le example
```

whereas desired result is often:

```
;; here is a
;; simple example
```

Of course, one can write a wrapper for comment-dwim, but I suspect/hope that there is a more correct solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't V (vimpulse-visual-toggle-line) already do that?

Linewise selection will select whole lines. (I use this all the time)
The behaviour you're talking about will occur if you're using v (vimpulse-visual-toggle-char).

Answer (score 0):

`comment-dwim` calls `comment-or-uncomment-region` to perform the actual commenting on the marked region. There is no option to extend the region to beginning of the first line and/or end of the last line. You will have to write a wrapper or [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp-manual/html_node/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions) `comment-or-uncomment-region` to achieve the effect you want.